# Android native date popup in phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker

I'm developing an phonegap android application.
I'm using input type date field in forms. When i run the app from browser clicking on date fields showing device native data widget.

But running the same files using phonegap the date fields not showing any popups. Android version is 4.1.1

How can i get the native date popup/widget when input type date field is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why input[type="date"] fields are not showing up the native date picker in a phonegap app, its probably not catching it. Note that androids standard browser is used, it may work in firefox or chrome, but probably not in the stock browser (app called "Internet").

But i would use the datepicker plugin for android. There are two available for android:

http://mrfoh.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/phonegap-android-datepicker-plugin/

http://bikasv.com/blog/2013/04/14/cordova-datepicker/

Comment: I found the second plugin after posting this question and worked on it. When the set button is clicked on the popup the date value is not showing up in the field given there..

Comment: can you confirm that the callback after clicking "set" gets triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better to use PhoneGap datepicker plugin. This [datepicker plugin](https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker/tree/3aeac69af2a7fdf14b2c1f6e060d7f8706728cf2) on GitHub supports PhoneGap 3.0 and Android.

Comment: Do you know how to theme it? I always get the pre-Holo theme, black and orange